# Post a form with ajax and display error in a div in case of error

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the code below, I have a form with some informations about an employee. I'd like feel in the password and post. If the password is correct the user is redirected to `/Dashboard` that it's ok.

When the password is wrong, I'd like show the error (`_ErrorPartial`) in `MyError` div and still see the form. I'd like see the form and the message in the div (`MyError`). With the code below, when the password is wrong, I see the error message but on a blank page and not a page with the layout + the form + the error message

Any idea ?

Thanks,

**My page :**

```
    @model MyApp.EmployeeModel
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Account/Login',
                    type: "Post",
                    data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                            alert('Im here');
                        $("#MyError").html(result);
                        //Here is code to detect error or not but removed
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="MyError"></div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor( m => m.FirstName)
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Username)
                @Html.LabelFor( m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                <input type="submit" class="jqClick" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

**Controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(EmployeeModel employeeModel)
{
    var Errors = new List<string>();
    var employee = .... //Get employee from DB
    if (employee == null)
    {
        Errors.Add("Employee trouble");
        return PartialView("_ErrorPartial", Errors.AsEnumerable());
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

**My _ErrorPartial view :**

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
<div id="DisplayError">
    @{ var error = string.Empty; }

    @foreach (var err in Model){
        error += err + "<br>";
    }
    @Html.Raw(error)
</div>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form? Have you tried to `return false` from the `click` function to prevent the default behavior?

Comment: Yes the form is submitted. I check the username/password if not I'd like display result in 'MyError'. I just tried 'return false' same. In the code I added an alert but I never hit the code no alert that's strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make some changes to your javascript code. First of all, replace jQuery selector `$(".")` with specific one, like `$(".jqClick")`. Second of all, **never** hardcode urls like `/Account/Login` in your code, use [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for that. And the third thing is, you have to prevent a default behavior of the submit button. See the changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".jqClick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
            type: "Post",
            data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Im here');
                if (result.redirectUrl)
                    window.location.href = result.redirectUrl;
                else
                    $("#MyError").html(result);
                //Here is code to detect error or not but removed
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also you need to change the `Login` action a little in order to make a redirect if a login is success:

```
public ActionResult Login(EmployeeModel employeeModel)
{
    var Errors = new List<string>();
    var employee = .... //Get employee from DB
    if (employee == null)
    {
        Errors.Add("Employee trouble");
        return PartialView("_ErrorPartial", Errors.AsEnumerable());
    }
    return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard") });
}
```

Comment: About the .jqClick it's already in the code but don't know what's I delete by mistake when I copy in the SO editor. LEt's me try your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The probable error that you throw from the server side, won't appear in success function. Instead you should have below

```
error:function(response)
{

   //your code here

}
```

Simply throw exception from the controller.

Comment: I don't want throw an exception (first because it's not an exception) but I'd like return the error view

Comment: For end user if password is wrong, it is an error (information message showing him that password is incorrect.

Comment: That's not the point here. I'd like hit the alert in the code and I never hit the alert. Thanks.